# Does Xamarin.Android supports custom Release configuration?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I just created single view Xamarin.Android project. 
Added configuration called `Release.Prod` and copied properties from `Release`.
Project built successfully, but when I want to archive apk it hangs on message `Please ensure that you are using a release configuration and that the "Use Shared Mono Runtime" option in your project's build options is unchecked`.
Use Shared Mono Runtime is unchecked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you are copying the configurations from release why don't you just use release?

Comment: @Scarnet I copied it for test. In real project we have "dev" and "prod" configurations. In code we using different server addresses (dev and prod). So configurations makes easier to switch between these servers.

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/demystifying-build-configurations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it supports. There is bug with packaging apk https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1760

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in the configuration manager.
I also use this for production configuration:

1. Build/Configuration Manager
2. Active solution configuration / New
3. Enter Name, copy settings from Release
4. Finally check the .csproj file as not all properties are copied from
   Release!